# LU factorization distribution over addition

Tags: linear-algebra, partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra, heat-equation

I am applying the Crank-Nicolson-Method to solve the diffusion equation in 1D.

I need to solve the implicit equation
$$Au^{j+1} = Bu^{j} \equiv b$$

Note that
$$A= \begin{bmatrix} 
\ddots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \mathstrut^{.^{.^{.}}} \\
\dotsc & -\alpha & 2(1+\alpha) & -\alpha & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \dotsc  \\ 
\dotsc & 0 & -\alpha & 2(1+\alpha) & -\alpha & 0 & 0 & 0 & \dotsc  \\ 
\dotsc & 0 & 0 & -\alpha & 2(1+\alpha) & -\alpha & 0 & 0 & \dotsc \\ 
\dotsc & 0 & 0 & 0 & -\alpha & 2(1+\alpha) & -\alpha & 0 & \dotsc  \\
\dotsc & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -\alpha & 2(1+\alpha) & -\alpha & \dotsc  \\
\mathstrut^{.^{.^{.}}} & \vdots &\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots  \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

The strategy is as follows: compute the LU factorization of $A,$ then store it, using the function dgttrf from LAPACK. Then, I can solve the implicit equation with the function dgttrs.

However, I have different species of particles, and so the alpha is different for all of them. I would therefore need to calculate the LU factorization for every alpha. Note though that
$$A=2\mathbf{I} + \alpha D.$$

This leads me to wonder: is it possible to just compute the LU factorization for D, store this, and then use this to determine the LU factorization for $A=2\mathbf{I} + \alpha D?$ In other words, are there any nice ways to convert:
$$2\mathbf{I} + \alpha PLU \to P'L'U'$$
Where $P', L',$ and $U'$ are new factorizations?

Comment: Isn't making a full LU factorization a bit overkill here? The matrix is tridiagonal so why not simply do https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tridiagonal_matrix_algorithm

Comment: @Winther OP is using a standard banded solver from LAPACK to produce a banded LU factorization and solve the linear system using $O(n)$ arithmetic operation. OP is not treating the linear systems as dense.

Comment: Ah ok good, then it's effectively doing the same thing.

Comment: @Winther Indeed. There is minute difference because the LAPACK routine allows for pivoting which can increase the upper bandwidth of the upper triangular factor by 1. This increase the storage requirement by two vectors whether they are needed or not. The Thomas algorithm doesn't do pivoting which saves operations and conserves memory.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is almost certainly no.

The key fact to notice is that your matrix $A = I + \alpha D$ is a rank $n$ perturbation of the matrix $\alpha D$. You cannot profit from applying the Sherman-Morrison-Woodbury formula in this situation. It is advantageous to apply this formula when $A = B + \alpha D$ and $B = UV^T$ and $U$, $V$ have $k \ll n$ columns.

Naturally, this does not prove that what you seek is impossible. However, there are simply so many people that would benefit so much from this that it seems unlikely that such a scheme hasn't been discovered at this point.

There is a very small chance that you could profit from the fact that $LU$ factorization of $A$ depends continuously on the parameter $\alpha$. If $\alpha_1 \approx \alpha_2$ and you have an LU factorization of $A(\alpha_1)$, then you may be solve $A(\alpha_2)x=b$ using the $LU$ factorization of $A(\alpha_1)$ and iterative refinement. Realistically, this will not yield a speedup on a modern computer as flops are cheap, but memory operations are expensive.

If speed is a critical issue, then your simplest course of action is to vectorize the solution of your differential equations using SIMD operations (search for AVX(2) instructions set, vector intrinsics, automatic vectorization + the name of your favorite compiler). Instead of solving 1 differential equation at a time you will solve, say, 8 equations at the same time. You will need control over the memory alignment of your data so that all arrays start at a cache line.

If you only have a single $\alpha$ then SIMD operations can still be applied if you adapt one of the standard algorithms for solving narrow banded linear systems in parallel. Examples include: cyclic reduction, the Spike algorithm.

Comment: Thank you. $A$ has a relatively simple form in this case. The subdiagonal, diagonal, and superdiagonal are only one "noncomplicated" value each (except for the top and bottom rows). So do you think it might be feasible to analytically determine the form of this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tridiagonal_matrix_algorithm  in terms of the parameter $\alpha ?$

Comment: @Jbag1212  I feel confident that an analytical formula can be determined. Cramer's rule applies to the general case, so there is a limit on how complicated the formula can be. However, while analytical formulas can be useful when we explore theoretical properties of objects, they are not always useful for practical calculations. It is a good exercise, but it would be a pleasant surprise if the result gave you a speedup.